# Is it possible to color code Jest output?

Tags: jestjs

I'm using Gulp and Jest, and I was wondering if anyone has found a way to color code test output in the console, similar to how it's done with reporters in Karma. The output is kind of blah, and I was hoping to make it a little easier to read.

Answer (score 7):

```
  "scripts":{  "test": "jest --colors" }   //package.json
```

Add the parameter --colors to your command while running jest..